# allauth problems extending SignupForm class

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I keep finding outdated solutions that don't seem to be working.

I'm trying to change the error messages from English to Hebrew, for my website in django-allauth, I haven't checked if their are any translations because I would like to write them myself anyhow.

I tried changing for example the duplicate email error with the following code.

**forms.py**

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm

class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    def raise_duplicate_email_error(self):
        raise forms.ValidationError("שם משתמש כבר קיים עם כתובת אימייל")
```

**base.py (base settings file)**

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'signup': 'website.forms.CustomSignupForm',
}
```

this resulted in the following error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sociallogin'
```

**Traceback:**

```
File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/sikumim/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/sikumim/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/sikumim/lib/python3.4/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/views.py" in dispatch
  38.         return super(SignupView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/sikumim/lib/python3.4/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in dispatch
  68.                                             **kwargs)
File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/sikumim/lib/python3.4/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in dispatch
  151.                                                           **kwargs)
File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/sikumim/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/sikumim/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get
  205.         form = self.get_form()
File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/sikumim/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_form
  74.         return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/sikumim/lib/python3.4/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py" in __init__
  289.         super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/sikumim/lib/python3.4/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py" in __init__
  223.         super(BaseSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /accounts/social/signup/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sociallogin'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the `CustomSignupForm` please..

Comment: you can see it in my post under forms.py

I want to keep the original form but just override the validation errors

Comment: Override the __init__()  method in your form and try

Comment: If I override the init method with: super(CustomSignupForm, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

You are inheriting from *allauth.account.forms.SignupForm* but using it in the setting *SOCIALACCOUNT_FORMS*, which is for social accounts. Your code should look like this:

**website/forms.py**

```
from allauth.socialaccount.forms import SignupForm

class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
     def raise_duplicate_email_error(self):
         raise forms.ValidationError("שם משתמש כבר קיים עם כתובת אימייל")
```

**settings.py**

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'signup': 'website.forms.CustomSignupForm',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite the `__init__()` method and define `sociallogin` as parameter, which then will not be passed to the `__init__()` method of the super class.

Like this:

```
def __init__(self, sociallogin=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```